# Bootstrap-tabdrop fix for modals?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

This question is based on the very useful bootstrap-tabdrop.js which doesn't appear to be actively supported by its creator: https://github.com/jschab/bootstrap-tabdrop.

How can I amend bootstrap-tabdrop to work inside modals? I thought I might need to call `tabdrop('layout')` when the modal loads but that doesn't work. Is there a change to the jQuery which anyone can recommend so that tabs stack nicely inside Bootstrap (3.2) modals?

Comment: Hey, have you figured out how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

i know it's an old question, but i had to deal with this issue today and come up with this:

```
$('#propValsModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    $('.nav-pills').tabdrop({
        'text': '<i class="icon-align-justify"></i> Choose Something'
    })
})
```

using the tabdrop "text" option you can at least instruct the user